# In Javascript: How to print an array, use arr.remove(i) to remove the first 2 elements, and print the new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to write a program that prints out an array, removes the first two elements of the array using arr.remove(i), and then prints out the new array. My program correctly removes the first two elements, but I am having trouble with getting the program to print out the lists in the correct format.

The program should print out:

```
Sam, Lisa, Laurie, Bob, Ryan
Laurie, Bob, Ryan
```

My program prints out:

```
Sam, Lisa, Laurie, Bob, RyanLaurie, Bob, Ryan
```

This is my program:

```
function start(){
    var arr = ["Sam", "Lisa", "Laurie", "Bob", "Ryan"];

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        print(arr[i]);

        if(i < arr.length - 1){
            print(", ");
        } 

    }


    var elem = arr.remove(0);
    var elem2 = arr.remove(0);


    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        print(arr[i]);

        if(i < arr.length - 1){

            print(", ");
        } 

    }

}
```

How can I fix this program so that it prints the new list on a different line?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: Your first for loop is unnecessary.

Comment: Where is this `Array.remove` method documented? Programming will go much better if **reading and respecting the contents of error messages**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `print("\n")` between the loops

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Array.remove` method. However, [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) can be used for removing elements:

```
if (index > -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

The second parameter of splice is the number of elements to remove. Note that splice modifies the array in place and returns a new array containing the elements that have been removed.